# Max of Data Holded by JAX-RS and Jax-WS

Tags: spring-boot, jax-rs, jax-ws

What is the maximum length of JSON object received by spring-boot application?
Thanks

Comment: That depends on your HTTP server choice and the amount of memory your application has. Can you give more details?

Comment: Hi
We had just start a project, now we word with embeded Tomcat spring boot
Thanks